# C# NLog Performance Class Variable

Tags: c#, performance, nlog

Using NLog appears to dramatically slow down the speed which I can access class variables.  When I run the code as is s1 is about 2 times slower that s2, which is expected.  But when I uncomment GetCurrentClassLogger line, s1 becomes about 800 times slower than s2. I am using .NET Core 2 and NLog 4.5.3.  Is this expected behavior?  What is causing this decrease in performance?  Thank you for any and all help!

```
class Program
{
    //private static readonly Logger _logger = LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger();
    private static readonly DateTime _epoch = new DateTime(1970, 1, 1);

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        DateTime epoch = new DateTime(1970, 1, 1);
        int count = 10000;
        Stopwatch s1 = new Stopwatch();
        Stopwatch s2 = new Stopwatch();

        s1.Start();
        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
        {
            var x = DateTime.UtcNow.Subtract(_epoch).TotalSeconds;
        }

        s1.Stop();

        s2.Start();
        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
        {
            var x = DateTime.UtcNow.Subtract(epoch).TotalSeconds;
        }

        s2.Stop();

        Console.WriteLine(s1.ElapsedTicks);
        Console.WriteLine(s2.ElapsedTicks);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Comment: I can't reproduce this - I get roughly the same results for `s1` and `s2` both times. I'm compiling and running this from the command line, with `/o+ /debug-` - how are you testing it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you first access a field on the class, it's necessary for the system to initialise all the static fields on the class - your benchmark is measuring this time.  With the first line commented out, that's simply setting `_epoch` to a new `DateTime` instance.  With the first line in, that's also calling off into the NLog code to initialise the logger.

The first time you access a field on the class is within your first loop, when you access `_epoch`.  That means it's within `s1`, so that's also measuring the class initialisation time.  If you modify your code like this:

```
class Program
{
    private static readonly Logger _logger = LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger();
    private static readonly DateTime _epoch = new DateTime(1970, 1, 1);

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        DateTime epoch = new DateTime(1970, 1, 1);
        int count = 10000;
        Stopwatch s1 = new Stopwatch();
        Stopwatch s2 = new Stopwatch();

        Stopwatch s3 = new Stopwatch();
        s3.Start();
        var e = _epoch;
        s3.Stop();

        s1.Start();
        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
        {
            var x = DateTime.UtcNow.Subtract(_epoch).TotalSeconds;
        }

        s1.Stop();

        s2.Start();
        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
        {
            var x = DateTime.UtcNow.Subtract(epoch).TotalSeconds;
        }

        s2.Stop();
        Console.WriteLine(s3.ElapsedTicks);
        Console.WriteLine(s1.ElapsedTicks);
        Console.WriteLine(s2.ElapsedTicks);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

You can see the majority of the time is spent within `s3`, where it's initialising those static members, due to the access of `_epoch` there.